# How do I get MSVC to see static constexpr member variables and functions at compile time in c++20?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, crtp

#### Background

I'm attempting to get access to a constexpr variable at compile time within a CRTP class.  Below is a MVCE of this.

```
template <class T>
struct CRTP {
    static constexpr int get_value() { 
        return T::value ; 
    }

    static constexpr int crtp_value = get_value();
};

struct Derived: CRTP<Derived> {
     static constexpr int value = 2;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(Derived::crtp_value == 2, "Should result in 2");
    return 0; 
}
```

I can't however run this on MSVC.  Am I doing something I shouldn't be doing here?  This works in other compilers, see godbolt links:

- [msvc (fails)](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:3,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:3,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:3,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:3,startLineNumber:14),source:%27+template+%3Cclass+T%3E%0A+struct+CRTP+%7B%0A+++++static+constexpr+int+get_value()+%7B+return+T::value+%3B+%7D%0A+++++static+constexpr+int+crtp_value+%3D+get_value()%3B%0A+%7D%3B%0A+%0A+struct+Derived:+CRTP%3CDerived%3E+%7B%0A++++++static+constexpr+int+value+%3D+2%3B%0A+%7D%3B%0A+%0A+int+main()+%7B%0A+++++static_assert(Derived::crtp_value+%3D%3D+2,+%22Should+result+in+2%22)%3B%0A+++++return+0%3B+%0A+%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27/std:c%2B%2B20+%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x64+msvc+v19.latest+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x64+msvc+v19.latest+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)
- [gcc (succeeds)](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:3,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:3,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:3,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:3,startLineNumber:14),source:%27+template+%3Cclass+T%3E%0A+struct+CRTP+%7B%0A+++++static+constexpr+int+get_value()+%7B+return+T::value+%3B+%7D%0A+++++static+constexpr+int+crtp_value+%3D+get_value()%3B%0A+%7D%3B%0A+%0A+struct+Derived:+CRTP%3CDerived%3E+%7B%0A++++++static+constexpr+int+value+%3D+2%3B%0A+%7D%3B%0A+%0A+int+main()+%7B%0A+++++static_assert(Derived::crtp_value+%3D%3D+2,+%22Should+result+in+2%22)%3B%0A+++++return+0%3B+%0A+%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)
- [clang (succeeds)](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:3,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:3,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:3,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:3,startLineNumber:14),source:%27+template+%3Cclass+T%3E%0A+struct+CRTP+%7B%0A+++++static+constexpr+int+get_value()+%7B+return+T::value+%3B+%7D%0A+++++static+constexpr+int+crtp_value+%3D+get_value()%3B%0A+%7D%3B%0A+%0A+struct+Derived:+CRTP%3CDerived%3E+%7B%0A++++++static+constexpr+int+value+%3D+2%3B%0A+%7D%3B%0A+%0A+int+main()+%7B%0A+++++static_assert(Derived::crtp_value+%3D%3D+2,+%22Should+result+in+2%22)%3B%0A+++++return+0%3B+%0A+%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1701,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

MSVC claims:

```
example.cpp
<source>(3): error C2039: 'value': is not a member of 'Derived'
<source>(7): note: see declaration of 'Derived'
<source>(3): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
<source>(7): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'CRTP<Derived>' being compiled
<source>(3): note: while compiling class template member function 'int CRTP<Derived>::get_value(void)'
<source>(3): error C2065: 'value': undeclared identifier
<source>(4): error C3615: constexpr function 'CRTP<Derived>::get_value' cannot result in a constant expression
<source>(3): note: failure was caused by control reaching the end of a constexpr function
<source>(12): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
<source>(12): note: failure was caused by a read of an uninitialized symbol
<source>(12): note: see usage of 'crtp_value'
Compiler returned: 2
```

which I cannot make heads or tails of.

#### Question

How do I get accessing static constexpr member variables or member functions from the derived class in CRTP to work in MSVC?

Comment: Can you compile `static_assert(Derived::get_value()==2);`?

Comment: @Red.Wave That also does not work, with nearly the exact same error.

Comment: I would tag **language-lawyer** instead of **compiler-errors**.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
template <class T>
struct CRTP {
    static const int crtp_value;
};
 
template <class T> const int CRTP <T>::crtp_value = T::value;
 
struct Derived : CRTP <Derived> {
    static constexpr int value = 2;
};
 
int main() {
    static_assert(Derived::value == 2, "Should result in 2");
}
```

Shouldn't be necessary, but hey.

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/938ns8cEE)

Comment: hmm, I don't think this works generally right? since `const int` is treated special by the standard to elide to a compile time constant under certain scenarios?  I tried making a dummy struct and it complained about it not being compile time even in GCC.  https://godbolt.org/z/5zeoKjs5h

Comment: Seems not.  Pesky MSVC, is `Derived::value` a non-primitive type, in your case?

Comment: For my specific case that I ran into this problem, it was actually an enum, but that appears to work with your solution even with `enum class` https://godbolt.org/z/Mr9rxKT6o. I figured I'd point that out since other people finding this question are going to be confused.

Comment: OK.  It's to do with non-trivial types, methinks.